# Dual Boot (Windows partition deleted) , but Still Appearing

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

In my MacBook Air "El Capitan", the Windows 10 was installed using Boot Camp, but the Windows 10 installation was corrupted (crashing).

Then I removed (adding space to MAC installation) the Windows 10 partition using Disk Utility.

Now when I turn On my MAC still message windows is appearing (showing MAC and Windows start options), and the default OS was Windows (appearing blue screen...).

**I want to remove Windows 10 option, but I don't know how to do it.**

[image]

[image]

```
 sh-3.2# diskutil list
 /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
    1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
    2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
    3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
 /dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                  Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                  22ACF9AD-58C6-401F-87D6-41696160E1FD
                                  Unencrypted
 sh-3.2#  gpt -r show /dev/disk0
       start       size  index  contents
           0          1         PMBR
           1          1         Pri GPT header
           2         32         Pri GPT table
          34          6         
          40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  235298960      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   235708600    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   236978136          7         
   236978143         32         Sec GPT table
   236978175          1         Sec GPT header
 sh-3.2#
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was follow:

[Ghost partition, Windows BSOD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225092/ghost-partition-windows-bsod)

1. Open a Terminal window and enter the following command.

   ```
   diskutil mount /dev/disk0s1
   ```
2. From a Finder window, open the EFI disk. Next open the EFI folder.
   Remove the Boot and Microsoft folders.
3. When finished, enter the command below.

   ```
   diskutil unmount /dev/disk0s1
   ```